# jquery autocomplete and laravel 5.1 throwing internal server error 500

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, autocomplete

I'km trying the autocomplete by selecting data from DB and getting back the response as json but all I got is internal server error, could it be a problem of csrf token?

this is the script

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input:text').bind({

            });
            $("#auto").autocomplete({
                minLength:2,
                source: '{{ URL('getdata') }}'

            });
        });
    </script>
```

and this in the controller:

```
public function getData(){

            $term = Input::get('term');

            $data = DB::table('items')->distinct()->select('item_name')->where('word', 'LIKE', $term.'%')->groupBy('word')->take(10)->get();
            foreach ($data as $v) {
                $return_array[] = array('value' => $v->word);
            }

            return Response::json($return_array);


    }
```

Comment: Maybe you can post an entry of your server log which shows what caused the 500 - Server Error? An CSRF-Token usually don't show up a 500-Error

Comment: Where can I find the server log?

Comment: What are you developing on? And what software do you use as server? Apache2 on Windows?

Comment: @92_egdeH MAMP on OSX

Comment: Your serverlogs should be around `/var/log/httpd` or see here: http://serverfault.com/questions/199462/mac-os-web-sharing-where-are-the-apache-logs Please look into the `error.log` if there's one.

Comment: I forgot to tell that the table I'm serching is FULLTEXT indexed.

Comment: You could also try manually going to the url using your browser to see any errors eg:<server-ip>/getdata?term="test"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in getData function, this one works.

```
public function getData(){

            $term = Input::get('term');

            $data = DB::table('items')->distinct()->select('item_name')->where('item_name', 'LIKE', $term.'%')->groupBy('item_name')->take(10)->get();
            foreach ($data as $v) {
                $return_array[] = array('value' => $v->item_name);
            }

            return Response::json($return_array);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

inspector.js:44 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/autocomplete?terms=d 500 (Internal Server Error) #
**This is my Controller*,

```
public function autosearch(Request $request){
                // dd($request->all());
                $query = $request->get('term','');
                $allproducts = Product::where('product_title','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')->get();

                $data = array();
                foreach($allproducts as $product)
                {
                    $data[] = array('value'=>$product->product_title,'id'=>$product->id);
                }
                if(count($data))
                {
                    return $data;
                }
                else{
                    return ['value'=>"No Result Found",'id'=>''];
                }
        }
```

This is my script tag:

```
<script>
           $(document).ready(function(){
               var path = "{{route('autosearch')}}"
               $('#search_text').autocomplete({

                   source:function(request,response)
                   {
                       $.ajax({

                           url:path,
                           dataType:"JSON",
                           data:{
                               term:request.term
                           },
                           success:function(data)
                           {
                               response(data);
                           }

                       });
                
                   },
                   minLength:1,

               });
           });
       </script>
```

This is my HTML Form:

```
                            <div class="col d-none d-xl-block">
                               
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="searchproduct">Search</label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input id="search_text" type="search" name="search" class="form-control py-2 pl-5 font-size-15 border-right-0 height-40 border-width-2 rounded-left-pill border-primary typeahead"  placeholder="Search for Products" aria-label="Search for Products" aria-describedby="searchProduct1" autocomplete="off" required>

                                        <div class="input-group-append">

                                            <button class="btn btn-primary height-40 py-2 px-3 rounded-right-pill" type="submit" id="searchProduct1">
                                                <span class="ec ec-search font-size-24"></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                
                            </div>
```